# How to map an Object?

Tags: javascript

For example, we can map an array like so:

```
IMGOINGTOBENUMBERS = ["1", "5", "19"];

IM_HAPPY = IMGOINGTOBENUMBERS.map(function(value){
        return +value;
});

console.log(IM_HAPPY);
```

On jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/87npme9e/1/

But, what about a regular JS Object? As we know `.map` only works on arrays.

Object:

```
IMGOINGTOBENUMBERS = {
    a: "1",
    b: "2"
}

NOT_HAPPY = IMGOINGTOBENUMBERS.map(function(value){
        return +value;
});

console.log(NOT_HAPPY);
```

On jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uyzqtpLd/2/

Comment: that's not json. that's just javascript. json is an encoding method for taking a JS data structure and sending it elsewhere as plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IMGOINGTOBENUMBERS = {
    a: "1",
    b: "2"
}



NOT_HAPPY =  Object.keys(IMGOINGTOBENUMBERS).map(function (key) {return IMGOINGTOBENUMBERS[key]});

console.log(NOT_HAPPY);
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting 0,1 instead of 1,2. I think it's grabbing the key index count, not the actual property.

Comment: Oh I see. you called the object name and stuck the key inside there. Clever.  Well, today I learned I can map objects and their properties :) Thanks!