# how to return an object under conditions

Tags: javascript, object

I’ve just started using objects (Im learning javascript).
So I have an object and this is what should happen:
The user insert some data; if there’s already this data in my object, I would return the object as it is;
but if keys and values are new, I have to return an object that contains my previous data and the new.

For example
let User = {
“name”:”Ed”,
“age”: 3
}
The user wants to add a new property to User, or maybe he just forgot that there’s already a name.
So I want to give him back his object, but with the new info only if they are really new.
I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241895/how-to-map-an-object) that sometimes you can use Map on the object and I tried but it doesn’t work...
I’m really lost and don’t know where to ask!

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Add your dataset and expected result...

Comment: You don't need to map anything. Just test if the property is already in the object. If not, add it.

Comment: Use `propertyName in User` to test if it's there. Use `User[propertyName] = value` to add it.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, if the user inputs a key-value pair but the key already exists then you want to return the object as-is, and if they input something with a new key you want to add it to the object. Here's how you can do that:

```js
if (!User.hasOwnProperty(inputKey)) {
    User[inputKey] = inputValue;
}
return User;
```

How this works:

- The expression `!User.hasOwnProperty(inputKey)` evaluates to True if the input key does not already exist in the object, or False if it does (this would be flipped without the `!`, meaning "not")
- If the key does not already exist in the object, we add the key-value pair to the object
- Then we return the object. If the key already existed, then the object was not modified. If the key didn't exist yet, we added it to the object.

Just replace `inputKey` and `inputValue` with the variable names for your input.

Hope this is what you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks ekcarney!